# Pokemon go camera

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to catch some pokemons with my camera, but I see the place that I'm showing whit my camera but the pokemon doesn't come on the camera, I can see the pokebal the backpag and other stuf but not the pokemon. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried turning around in a circle? the pokemon is not always right in front of you, it can be off to the sides sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking around. There should be some arrows on the side of the screen to point you in the right direction.